# Assets from amazon s3 do not load when deployed to a mobile device

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, augmented-reality, vuforia

This is my first attempt to use amazon s3 and I am still learning.
I am attempting to load an asset bundle from Amazon s3 for a simple AR app. I am using Vuforia to load a spider when the camera is looking at a specific image. This asset worked perfectly fine when not loaded from amazon but now the asset never gets loaded when build to my phone, however it does get loaded in unity. I have set the permission so everyone can read from the asset bundle.

I am not sure if there is something I need to do in the android SDK or not.

This is my script used to load the asset from amazon s3:

```
public Text debugText;
// initialization
void Start()
{
    string url = "This is a url";
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForReq(www));


}

IEnumerator WaitForReq(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        GameObject SPIDER = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset("SPIDER");


        //For debugging, see if asset is being loaded
        debugText.text = ("Object has loaded");


        //Instantiates at the location of where the ImageTarget is
        var loadedAsset = Instantiate(SPIDER, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity); 
        //Makes transform of loadedAsset the transform of the ImageTarget 
        loadedAsset.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        loadedAsset.gameObject.active = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
}
```

Edit: adding loggs

```
08-26 13:45:07.598: I/Unity(10633): StopVuforia
08-26 13:45:07.598: I/Unity(10633):  
08-26 13:45:07.598: I/Unity(10633): (Filename: 
./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
08-26 13:45:46.320: W/UnityMain(10633): type=1400 audit(0.0:105566): avc: 
denied { read } for name="version" dev="proc" ino=4026532375 
scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 
tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=1024 pcomm="main" pgid=10633 
pgcomm="name.name"
08-26 13:45:46.403: I/Unity(10633): StartVuforia
08-26 13:45:46.403: I/Unity(10633):  
08-26 13:45:46.403: I/Unity(10633): (Filename: 
./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
08-26 13:45:46.400: W/UnityMain(10633): type=1400 audit(0.0:105567): avc: 
denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15357 
scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 
tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=1024 pcomm="main" pgid=10633 
pgcomm="name.name"
08-26 13:46:19.877: I/Unity(10633): StopVuforia
08-26 13:46:19.877: I/Unity(10633):  
08-26 13:46:19.877: I/Unity(10633): (Filename: 
./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
08-26 13:46:27.050: W/UnityMain(10633): type=1400 audit(0.0:105655): avc:         denied { read } for name="version" dev="proc" ino=4026532375 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=1024 pcomm="main" pgid=10633 pgcomm="name.name"
08-26 13:46:27.089: I/Unity(10633): StartVuforia
08-26 13:46:27.089: I/Unity(10633):  
08-26 13:46:27.089: I/Unity(10633): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
08-26 13:46:27.080: W/UnityMain(10633): type=1400 audit(0.0:105656): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15357 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=1024 pcomm="main" pgid=10633 pgcomm="name.name"
```

Comment: Do you get any logging? You can connect to your device to Unity and run the scene on it: [docs](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing)
Can you share the output in the console?

Comment: I have added the Logs from the android device manager. Thank you so much for helping me out btw. I had no idea about those logs and it took me awhile to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thank you dome12b. Thanks to you for posting how to get the android debugger going I was able to solve it myself. Turns out way back during the beginning of me starting this project, I created the assets bundle in unity to the wrong build target. All I had to do was Change the build target for the asset bundle to android and presto, it works now!. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction.